# e-xact api for groovy

Tags: api, rest, groovy

here we go again in the unauthenticated problem so here is the code

```
  package exact
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
@Grab(group='org.json', module='json', version='20090211')
import org.json.JSONObject

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import wslite.http.auth.*

//class Payment {
    public void payment(Object request) throws Exception{
        try{
        def http = new RESTClient('https://api.demo.e-xact.com')
        //http.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic '+"AD8007-01:SoIj42u7".getBytes('iso-8859-1').encodeBase64()
                 def resp =http.post(
                 path:'/transaction/v8',
                  body:[ExactID:'AD8007-01', 
                        Password:'SoIj42u7',
                        Transaction_Type:'00',
                        DollarAmount:'7552',
                        Card_Number:'5500000000000004',
                        Transaction_tag:'901975484',
                        Authorization_Num:'ET4653',
                        Expiry_Date:'1212',
                        CardHolderName:'Donald Duck',
                        CVD_Presence_Ind:'0',
                        Client_IP:'250.232.25.155'
                      ],
                        requestContentType : JSON
                )
                 def a = resp.data
                 print a

        }catch ( HttpResponseException ex ){
        println ex.getResponse().getData()
    }


}

payment(null)
```

here is the link for the documentation [a link]https://hostedcheckout.zendesk.com/entries/231362-Transaction-Processing-API-Reference-Guide#1.2.1

here is the error

```
 May 29, 2014 3:24:38 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
Unauthorized Request (bad or missing credentials).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the parameters from

```
 ExactID:'AD8007-01', 
    Password:'SoIj42u7',
    Transaction_Type:'00',
    DollarAmount:'7552',
    Card_Number:'5500000000000004',
    Transaction_tag:'901975484',
    Expiry_Date:'1212',
    CardHolderName:'Donald Duck',
```

to this format

```
gateway_id:'AD8055-01',
    password:'nWxolXy4',
    transaction_type:'00',
    amount:75.54f,
    cardholder_name:'Donald Duck',
    cc_number:'5500000000000004',
    cc_expiry:'0351',
    transaction_tag:'1211'
```